# Twilio chat - client channels list is always nil

Tags: swift, chat, twilio, twilio-api

For embedded chat feature in an app we are using Twilio's `Programmable Chat` framework. `TwilioChatClient` was created as follows:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let token = utils.user_token {
        setupTwilio(token: token)
    }else {
        utils.getAccessToken({
            user_token in

            if let token = user_token as String! {
                self.setupTwilio(token: token)
            }
        })
    }
} 

private func setupTwilio(token: String) {
    if client == nil {
        client = TwilioChatClient(token: token, properties: nil, delegate: self)
    }
}
```

According to twilio documentation, we need `client?.channelsList()` to create, get, join, even delete a channel and `client?.channelsList()` we get is always nil.
FYI, the token is used for creating `client` is valid and `client` is not nil. Can someone tell me why we're getting nil for `client?.channelsList()`? Or are we missing something?

Another lame question, what are the differences between `TwilioIPMessagingClient` and `TwilioChatClient`? I assumed that `TwilioChatClient` is an upgrade of `TwilioIPMessagingClient`, but haven't found any clear documentation. Can anyone please get me the migration guide?

#### Edit

P.S.
We did wait for client to be initialized at delegate method; like

```
extension ChatViewController: TwilioChatClientDelegate {
    func chatClient(_ client: TwilioChatClient!, synchronizationStatusChanged status: TCHClientSynchronizationStatus) {
         guard status != .completed else {
             print("Show failed alert")
             return
         }

         guard client.channelsList() != nil else {
             print("channel list is nil");
             return
         }

         // create and/or join channel
         joinChatChannel();
   }
}
```

But flow always fails at second `guard`.

Comment: Hi how to know other user is online or offline .may you have me please?

Answer (score 1):

`client.channelsList()` should be non-nil once the client reaches the `. completed` state in the code above.  This indicates to me there may be some permission issue or other error occurring.

To diagnose this further, it would be helpful to review a complete log from your application in the context of your Twilio account.  May I ask that you open a ticket with Twilio support containing a log (https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) and reference this SO post?  That will help it get routed to our team and we can work with you 1:1 on this issue.  We'll update this post at the end with the resolution to help others.

Also, a quick note on `TCHClientSynchronizationStatus` - there are other non-error states aside from `.completed`, just mentioning this so you know the client will pass through multiple states before .completed that do not necessarily indicate an error as is being print()ed today in your code snippet.

Comment: thank you for your response. One of our developer has already opened a ticket regarding this issue. I will add complete log there or open a new ticket if that seems inappropriate after I review. As we are at weekend, I'm afraid I have to do it on Sunday. And thank you again for the note about the Status. We do will implement features for other statuses. We are just focusing on making it work right now.

Answer (score 0):

With regards the channelList being nil. are you waiting for the SDK to complete init, and be ready for use?

You can take a look at how to do this here:  https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/initializing-sdk-clients#ios

Yes, IP Messaging was renamed to Programmable Chat.  You can find the iOS migration guide here:  https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/migration-guide-ios-0160

Hope that helps!

Comment: Please check edited part of the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this same snag. I was able to resolve this by following these steps after the connection comes back successful, in your delegate:

- dispatch to a background thread
- call Thread.sleepForTimeInterval to wait for 1 second
- dispatch back to the main thread
- then call your loadChannels method

  ```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{       
      [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [self loadChannelList];    
      });
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@rbeiter** and Twilio for their sincere support.
The problem was, we were missing the `identity` in token information. The Twilio log indicated that at

> 2017-03-15 06:38:03.842117 TwilioChatApplication[1053:482861] TNTwilsockClientImpl[3]: 0x16e2b7000 | 03/15/06:38:03.841 | INFO | 2 | TNTwilsockClientImpl | Close description: {"code":401,"status":"'identity' not present in token grants"}

According to **rbeiter**, If you are using one of Twilio's generators to build the token, this can be solved by setting the identity key in the grants hash or object.